# View XML to be sent over web reference via Visual Studio

Tags: c#, xml, visual-studio-2008, web-services, asmx

Could someone tell me how to view the XML to be sent via web reference while debugging Visual Studio (i.e. see the actual XML with all tags too?) I'm having a "There is an error in this XML Document (4, 56)." error.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: @David: were you aware that Microsoft now considers ASMX web services to be "legacy technology"? That goes for web references as well.

Comment: If it were only ASMX, I wouldn't have a problem, but it's using a (Non-.net) database system and... well, my hand is forced in this one. Just want to find out though, what is the current non-legacy that achieves the same thing? I still use Linq to Sql for Winforms apps too, so I guess I'm super legacy eh, seen as that's now "dead technology", lol.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Any HTTP debugging tool should suffice, e.g. [Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/)